# Shared Preferences not working as expect

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating an android application for a university project and I am having trouble with using Shared Preferences to save user login details. I want the application to start at a particular page depending on whether or not the user has logged in before, if so they shouldn't need to login again but they should be taken to their home page.

My login activity is as follows:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MANAGER_PASSWORD = "CLUBHUB";
private static final String PLAYER_PASSWORD = "PLAYER";
private static final String LOGIN_ERROR = "Incorrect password";

public static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "login_storage";

public static final String PASSWORD_KEY = "password";

private Context ctx;

EditText password;
Button login;
SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);




    sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String userInput = password.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

            editor.putString(PASSWORD_KEY, userInput);

            editor.commit();

            if (userInput.equals(MANAGER_PASSWORD)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ManagerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (userInput.equals(PLAYER_PASSWORD)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, PlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if ((userInput != MANAGER_PASSWORD) || (userInput != PLAYER_PASSWORD)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LOGIN_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                password.setText("");
            }

        }

    });

    setLoginPage();

}

private void setLoginPage() {

    EditText enterPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);
    String password = enterPassword.getText().toString();

    String check = sp.getString(PASSWORD_KEY, password);

    if (check.equals(MANAGER_PASSWORD)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ManagerActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (check.equals(PLAYER_PASSWORD)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, PlayerActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
}
```

The initial first-time login was working fine, but now that I have tried to add SharedPreferences functionality nothing is working and I just cannot get the Shared Preferences to work. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Logcat

```
12-25 16:15:12.460    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14044: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14048: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-25 16:15:13.701    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:13.941    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
12-25 16:15:13.941    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13945: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
12-25 16:15:13.941    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 409: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 431: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-25 16:15:13.951    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:14.221    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 196K, 13% free 7608K/8711K, paused 37ms, total 38ms
12-25 16:15:14.221    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 8.701MB for 433688-byte allocation
12-25 16:15:14.331    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 13% free 8027K/9159K, paused 37ms+9ms, total 112ms
12-25 16:15:14.331    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 94ms
12-25 16:15:14.341    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
12-25 16:15:14.341    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 372: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-25 16:15:14.351    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:14.351    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
12-25 16:15:14.351    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 374: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
12-25 16:15:14.351    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-25 16:15:14.762    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
12-25 16:15:14.862    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))+/./(
12-25 16:15:15.002    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_rhea.so
12-25 16:15:15.092    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateContext() config: 19 context: 0x49b56d08, VC context 1, Thread 2595
12-25 16:15:15.092    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x49b56d80, VC surface: 1, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.092    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x49b56d80, 0x49b56d80) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.202    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-25 16:15:15.232    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)))d:+(
12-25 16:15:15.773    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))d/(.8
12-25 16:15:15.783    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.783    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x49b56d80, android window 0x4a05fe88, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.843    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4a1e76f0, VC surface: 2, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.843    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4a1e76f0, 0x4a1e76f0) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:15.873    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))f/d+(
12-25 16:15:16.464    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))eadc8
12-25 16:15:16.474    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:16.474    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4a1e76f0, android window 0x4a2466d0, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:16.544    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 145K, 12% free 8362K/9415K, paused 26ms+5ms, total 57ms
12-25 16:15:16.844    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4a246c28, VC surface: 3, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:16.844    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4a246c28, 0x4a246c28) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:16.874    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+(c8b(
12-25 16:15:17.264    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+(cbc(
12-25 16:15:17.264    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.264    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4a246c28, android window 0x4a0a34a8, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.264    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4a040e18, 0x4a040e18) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.274    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.354    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4a41a880, VC surface: 5, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.354    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4a41a880, 0x4a41a880) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.384    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+(e8d8
12-25 16:15:17.595    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)+:-(
12-25 16:15:17.595    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.595    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4a41a880, android window 0x4a41a280, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.665    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x419d5a10, VC surface: 6, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.665    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x419d5a10, 0x419d5a10) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.695    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)++,,c8
12-25 16:15:17.885    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+,8)b(
12-25 16:15:17.885    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.885    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x419d5a10, android window 0x4b605818, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.965    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4b605130, VC surface: 7, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.965    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4b605130, 0x4b605130) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:17.995    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+.8db(
12-25 16:15:18.175    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+-cd:8
12-25 16:15:18.175    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.185    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4b605130, android window 0x4b5e6e40, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.215    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 175K, 11% free 8746K/9799K, paused 66ms+5ms, total 309ms
12-25 16:15:18.215    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
12-25 16:15:18.275    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4b6052c8, VC surface: 8, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.275    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4b6052c8, 0x4b6052c8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.315    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))),*)8
12-25 16:15:18.596    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+,8d/(
12-25 16:15:18.596    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.596    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4b6052c8, android window 0x4b73dd68, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.666    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4b759eb8, VC surface: 9, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.666    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4b759eb8, 0x4b759eb8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.696    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+/:.,8
12-25 16:15:18.906    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+8d/f(
12-25 16:15:18.906    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.916    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4b759eb8, android window 0x4b73dd68, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.986    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4da52520, VC surface: 10, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:18.986    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4da52520, 0x4da52520) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.016    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+:f,c(
12-25 16:15:19.206    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+a)-.8
12-25 16:15:19.206    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.206    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4da52520, android window 0x4da23ad0, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.276    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4da52418, VC surface: 11, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.276    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4da52418, 0x4da52418) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.306    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+c+.b(
12-25 16:15:19.426    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 176K, 11% free 9128K/10183K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 278ms
12-25 16:15:19.426    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
12-25 16:15:19.506    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+cace8
12-25 16:15:19.516    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.516    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4da52418, android window 0x4da8c3f8, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.607    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4a0374f0, VC surface: 12, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.607    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4a0374f0, 0x4a0374f0) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.637    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+*b)(8
12-25 16:15:19.917    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+8b:,8
12-25 16:15:19.927    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.927    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4a0374f0, android window 0x4b6c91c8, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.997    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4b86b4e8, VC surface: 13, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:19.997    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4b86b4e8, 0x4b86b4e8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.037    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+f,--(
12-25 16:15:20.287    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+e8::8
12-25 16:15:20.287    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.287    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4b86b4e8, android window 0x4da8b9e8, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.357    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e0948d0, VC surface: 14, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.357    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e0948d0, 0x4e0948d0) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.387    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),(::8(
12-25 16:15:20.568    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),*df+(
12-25 16:15:20.568    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.568    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4e0948d0, android window 0x4e0942d0, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.648    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e089030, VC surface: 15, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.648    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e089030, 0x4e089030) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.678    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),)fb+(
12-25 16:15:20.818    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 11% free 9555K/10631K, paused 41ms+5ms, total 241ms
12-25 16:15:20.818    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
12-25 16:15:20.888    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),,)ef(
12-25 16:15:20.888    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.888    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4e089030, android window 0x4dfb5de0, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.968    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4dfbb1f8, VC surface: 16, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:20.968    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4dfbb1f8, 0x4dfbb1f8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.008    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+8/+:8
12-25 16:15:21.178    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,))f.d*(
12-25 16:15:21.178    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.178    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4dfbb1f8, android window 0x4a245b60, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.248    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e0ace80, VC surface: 17, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.248    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e0ace80, 0x4e0ace80) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.278    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),,b88(
12-25 16:15:21.448    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),.e*d(
12-25 16:15:21.448    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.458    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4e0ace80, android window 0x4dfa9188, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.538    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4dfa96f8, VC surface: 18, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.538    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4dfa96f8, 0x4dfa96f8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.568    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),/(+a(
12-25 16:15:21.769    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),8,b.(
12-25 16:15:21.769    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.769    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4dfa96f8, android window 0x4dfe8408, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.839    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e0aa400, VC surface: 19, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.839    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e0aa400, 0x4e0aa400) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:21.869    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),:.-d(
12-25 16:15:22.079    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),b:d,8
12-25 16:15:22.079    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.079    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4e0aa400, android window 0x4e086860, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.169    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e0160b8, VC surface: 20, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.169    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e0160b8, 0x4e0160b8) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.199    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),aa(-8
12-25 16:15:22.359    2595-2599/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 11% free 10042K/11207K, paused 42ms+5ms, total 257ms
12-25 16:15:22.700    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,)+)/+:8
12-25 16:15:22.700    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.700    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x4e0160b8, android window 0x4e0c6fc0, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.780    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4e061248, VC surface: 21, Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.780    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/BRCM_EGL﹕ eglMakeCurrent(0x49b56d08, 0x4e061248, 0x4e061248) Thread: 2595
12-25 16:15:22.820    2595-2595/com.example.myacer.clubhub D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DH delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),.,8e8
```

Comment: when you say nothing is working, Kindly state what you wanted the code to do and what is not happening?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I have in the onClickListener, editor.putString(Password_KEY, userInput). I only need to save the password.

Comment: @PankajNimgade I had an initial login page that just has a password input. Depending upon the password input the user will be taken to different activities. Obviously I don't want the user to have to enter the password every time they start the application so I tried to implement SharedPreferences functionality to save the password entered by the user for their next visit. This is where I am now having trouble. When I launch the application it fails to open at all

Comment: Make sure `ManagerActivity` and `PlayerActivity` are defined correctly in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Ok, Is your application is crashing when you launch it?    or Is it not going to respective activity if user has already logged in?  or Is the password you are trying to save is not saved ?

Comment: The code to commit the shared preferences is correct. You can check this by adding a new button into your activity which will retrieve you the saved data into the new textview/edittext or toast it.

Comment: STORING PASSWORDS IN CLEARTEXT IS AN UNFORGIVABLE SIN. Never store passwords is clear text. Always encrypt them. Other than that, I'm on mobile right now, so I'll try to solve your problem when I get to my PC

Comment: @PankajNimgade application is now crashing on launch - white screen off death i could call it. Before adding any sharedpreferences code all login functionality was working correctly, users were being directed to their particular activity whether they were a manager or player

Comment: @PratyushYadav thanks for the advice! I will have a look at encryption next

Comment: ok, on the Log what error are you getting when your application crashes ?

Comment: @PankajNimgade struggling to make much sense of the logcat. only error I can find is _com.example.myacer.clubhub E/SensorManager﹕ thread start_, then repeating eglMakeCurrent, eglDestroySurface and registerListener over and over

Comment: Why don't you show your logcat?

Comment: @LiamC, you should be getting some error which is inside one of your activity, did you mention name of your activities you want to open in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to  `sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`